# I can't get result of Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initState();
  }
  _initState() async {
    _geIdsList().then((result) {
      _idList = result;
      print('result $_idList');
    }, onError: (e) {
      print('error $e');
    });
  }
```

Then there's my function to fetch the IDs from Firestore:

```
Future<List<String>> _geIdsList() async {
  List<String> ids = [];
  StreamSubscription stream;
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  Geoflutterfire geo;
  var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('locations');
  geo = Geoflutterfire();
  var location = new Location();
  var pos = await location.getLocation();
  var radius = BehaviorSubject<double>.seeded(10.0);
  GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude.toDouble(), longitude: pos.longitude.toDouble());

  stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
    return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
        center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
  }).listen((List<DocumentSnapshot>  documentList) {
    Future.forEach(documentList, (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)   {
        print('document here ... $documentSnapshot' );
        print(documentSnapshot.data['id']);
        var id = documentSnapshot.data['id'].toString();
        ids.add(id);
    }).whenComplete(() {
      stream.cancel();
      print('ids from function $ids');
      return ids;
    });
  });
}
```

Now _getIdsList() is working fine and the

> when complete print('ids from function $ids');

line, prints the IDs List and I'm unable to understand why it doesn't work in my initState. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you need to call `_geIdsList` when you can simply use `_idList = ids` inside `whenComplete()`

Comment: you're right but my purpose is to call another function when I get this IDs list and the _idList List is there just to verify I can get the job done in the initState. the question is why it doesn't work? I though that's the right way to deal with a Future.

Comment: The reason why I suggested that answer is because I don't have access to your variables. Can you provide some other code that I can run on my machine too?

Comment: the variables you cant access are coming from some plugins like import 'dart:async';

cloud_firestore.dart';
geoflutterfire.dart';
location.dart';
firebase_database.dart';
rxdart.dart';  and the code I provided is working fine, despite I expect it to works differently in the initState block and I'm not sure that's the right way to call a Future.

Comment: Yes, I know I can import those files but before that I have to add those packages in my `pubspec.yaml`, do `flutter packages get`, import it then, bla bla, so I thought if you can provide an easy to reproduce code, it would help!